# How to globally replace () with \left(\right) in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I find myself barely using `()`. Instead, I always use `\left(\right)`. Keeping typing that long string really kills me.

I have tried this, but no luck.

```
\DeclareMathOperator{(}{\left(}
\DeclareMathOperator{)}{\right)}
```

Hence, I am looking for a way that forces the compiler to interpret `()` into `\left(\right)` in math mode.

Comment: IMO this is a bad idea: automatic sizing should be used sparingly, since it too often chooses larger delimiters than necessary.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks a lot for your kind advice. So the best way would be manually selecting the size every time? Wont that be a bit troublesome?

Comment: You could have `(` and `)` being active characters, but I would suggest using the [`nath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nath) package. Also I think this is a really bad idea.